# Ffill and BFill in pandas using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to solve a question where we need to use ffill and bfill along with conditions.

DataFrame :

```
A 100
B NULL
C NULL
D 100
E NULL
F 103
```

Output DataFrame :

```
A 100
B 100
C 100
D 100
E NULL
F 103
```

Rows B and C are populated with 100 because value of A = value of D = 100.
Row E is unpopulated because value of D!=value of F

Has anyone came across such questions ?

I tried using FFill and BFill .

Answer (score 0):

You can compute both [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) and only keep the values that are identical using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
f = df['col2'].ffill()
b = df['col2'].bfill()

df['new'] = f.where(f.eq(b))
```

*NB. I am assuming `NULL` are `NaNs`, else first `replace('NULL', np.nan)`.*

Output (as new column for clarity):

```
  col1   col2    new
0    A  100.0  100.0
1    B    NaN  100.0
2    C    NaN  100.0
3    D  100.0  100.0
4    E    NaN    NaN
5    F  103.0  103.0
```

Comment: Did you comment on the answer? I saw a notification but it was gone when the page loaded

Comment: @Karthik - don't forget to acknowledge others help - if the post helps you!